# Why I'm getting this error?

Tags: linux

I have follow the koha demo and still cannot install the koha on ubuntu

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRebg.jpg]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). The link leads to our sister site, but the reasoning is universal.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the wget command you typed `-0` instead of `-O` like it should be. It's supposed to be an uppercase "o", as in the `--output` option.
2. You ran the commands separately, but they're meant to be piped from wget to apt-key.

   These specific commands are supposed to be used together, as wget's `-O -` tells it to write to stdout and apt's `-` tells it to read from stdin, i.e. `wget ... | sudo apt-key ...`.

   When run separately, the reason apt-key does nothing is because the `-` tells it to read the key from stdin – which currently is your keyboard, so it's waiting for your input.

   (Though the output is going to be text, so you *could* just copy-paste the wget output into apt-key manually, finishing with Ctrl-D.)